# Struggling with capital letters and xlm namespace while creating a block for a new module

Tags: layout, blocks

I am trying to create a block containing a method callable on my template

I believe i doing something wrong with capital letters or declaration conventions in my xml files.
I did not manage to declare properly my block in the layout file.

can anyone help ?

local/Maticode/WebLog/etc/config.xml :

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <config>
           <modules>
              <Maticode_WebLog>
                 <version>
                 0.1.0
                 </version>
              </Maticode_WebLog>
           </modules>


           <frontend>

               <routers>           
                   <weblog>
                      <use>standard</use>
                      <args>
                       <module>Maticode_WebLog</module>
                      <frontName>weblog</frontName>
                      </args>
                 </weblog>
               </routers>

                 <layout>
         <updates>
                <weblog>
                     <file>webloglayout.xml</file>
                </weblog>
                 </updates>
         </layout>



                </frontend>   

                     <global>
                          <blocks>
                             <weblog>
                                <class>Maticode_WebLog_Block</class>
                            </weblog>
                          </blocks>
                       </global>

                 </config>
```

local/Maticode/WebLog/Block/monblock.php:

```
         <?php
           class Maticode_WebLog_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
          {
             public function methodblock()
             {
               return 'informations de mon block !!';
             }
           }
```

design/frontend/base/default/layout/webloglayout.xml:

```
         <layout version="0.1.0">
           <weblog_index_index>
             <reference name="root">
               <!--http://localhost/magento/weblog/ outputs : 'here'-->

               <!--  <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="weblog.phtml" />-->

               <!--this does not display the template  -->
         <block type="weblog/monblock" name="afficher_monbloc" template="weblog.phtml" />
             </reference>
           </weblog_index_index>
         </layout>
```

design/frontend/base/default/template/weblog.phtml:

```
        <?php
      echo 'here';     
      echo $this->methodblock();
         ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register Block in config.xml file as follows (inside config tag)

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <weblog>
            <class>Maticode_WebLog_Block</class>
        </weblog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

And "local/Maticode/WebLog/Block/monblock.php" this file should be "local/Maticode/WebLog/Block/Monblock.php"

and layout should be

```
<weblog_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="weblog/monblock" name="afficher_monbloc" template="weblog.phtml" />
    </reference>
</weblog_index_index>
```

Comment: monblock.php works also!name="content" instead of name="root" solved the problem. i don't know why and how does this reference attributes work...